# Assign event from partial class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, partial-classes

I have made a winform application in c#. Now I added a class named `Main_Form_1`.
In `Main_Form`, there are some `click events` that I copied in `Main_Form_1`.

```
// Main_Form.cs
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{
    ...
    // code here
    ...
}

// Main_Form_1.cs
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{
    private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to assign this `SomeButton_Click` event, but I can not see the events in the property window. How can I assign this event to `SomeButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean the *event handler* `SomeButton_Click` here. You can add it to the `Click` event of button "SomeButton" with: `SomeButton.Click += SomeButton_Click;`